# Does SignalR send response to all the connections including the current connection, or all but excluding the current?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Let's say for example I've a button that displays `alert` to all the users. When I click the button, all the connected clients will see the `alert`.

And let's say this is done by calling a **Server Method** from client, which calls a function on `Client` that show an alert.

For example:

```
public class DemoHub : Hub {
    public void ShowAlert(String message) {
        Clients.All.showAlertMessage(message);
    }
}
```

This is a server method in hub, that calls the client function to show alert message.

My question is, does the alert will be shown to the current client too? I mean, if I click the button, do I see the alert myself in this case?

*Note: the above scenario is not a real scenario, that is just a similar illustration of my issue as my current scenario is rather complex to explain.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To broadcast to ALL connections *including* the caller you would use

```
Clients.All.showAlertMessage(message);
```

To broadcast to ALL EXCEPT the caller you will want to use the method

```
Clients.Others.showAlertMessage(message);
```

Can find more documentation on this at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromhub

This method above will broadcast to all connections except the current one which I believe is what you are looking for

Comment: ok, so, `Clients.All` broadcast all connections including the current, and `Clients.Others` broadcast all the connections excluding the current. Is that correct?

Comment: then, if I click the button I will see the alert myself, if `Client.All` used?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I will update my answer accordingly. .All includes current, .Others does not